# initializing network connection in Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, internet-connection

I have installed Win 7 in Virtual Box

I don't know how add network connections in windows 7.

My Win7 Network Configuration:

[image]

My Host OS:

[image]

Edit:

My network details in Ubuntu and Win7(VirtualBox)

Ubuntu is connected to Internet. No Proxy. Virtual Box uses NAT.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: I couldn't add my image in content since my reputation <10. So, I added them in comments

Comment: No, you should add them inside post. Other members will edit your post and include those images in it if they are appropriate. If the system doesn't allow you to post URLs (no more 2 are allowed for new users), you should include them in backticks `.

Comment: Now, to the question: Does Ubuntu connect to the Internet? Are you behind a proxy or firewall? Also, does VirtualBox use NAT or bridge connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should set up DNS in Windows. To do this:

1. Click on *Change Adapter Settings* link left of network view.
2. Right-click on your Network Adapter. Choose Properties.
3. This window will appear:

   [image: Local Area Connection Properties]

   Select item that selected in the above example and click Properties.
4. This window will appear:

   [image: IPv4 Properties]

   Enter these DNS servers into the appropriate fields:

   ```
   10.1.31.1
   10.1.0.5
   ```
5. Click OK twice. Your network should work fine.

Refer to [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7) for further information.

Comment: Shall I keep it as NAT itself.

and my network is a wired connection. I am doing this in college

Comment: Yes, unless different setting will be required.